# How to do dynamic matplotlib plotting with a fixed pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation

I have a dataframe called `benchmark_returns` and `strategy_returns`. Both have the same timespan. I want to find a way to plot the datapoints in a nice animation style so that it shows all the points loading in gradually. I am aware that there is a `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()`, however this typically is only used for a real-time updating of csv files etc but in my case I know all the data I want to use.

I have also tried using the crude `plt.pause(0.01)` method, however this drastically slows down as the number of points get plotted.

Here is my code so far

```
x = benchmark_returns.index
y = benchmark_returns['Crypto 30'] 
y2 = benchmark_returns['Dow Jones 30']
y3 = benchmark_returns['NASDAQ'] 
y4 = benchmark_returns['S&P 500']


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, color='k')
line2, = ax.plot(x, y2, color = 'b')
line3, = ax.plot(x, y3, color = 'r')
line4, = ax.plot(x, y4, color = 'g')

def update(num, x, y, y2, y3, y4, line): 
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])
    line2.set_data(x[:num], y2[:num])
    line3.set_data(x[:num], y3[:num])
    line4.set_data(x[:num], y4[:num])

    return line, line2, line3, line4,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, fargs=[x, y, y2, y3, y4, line], 
                              interval = 1, blit = True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [`matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation.html). It operates similar to `FuncAnimation` in that you can specify the frame interval, looping behavior, etc, but all the plotting is done at once, before the animation step. Here is an example

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import ArtistAnimation

n = 150
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, n)
df = pd.DataFrame({'cos(x)' : np.cos(x), 
                   'sin(x)' : np.sin(x),
                   'tan(x)' : np.tan(x),
                   'sin(cos(x))' : np.sin(np.cos(x))})

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10,10))
lines = []
artists = [[]]
for ax, col in zip(axs.flatten(), df.columns.values):
    lines.append(ax.plot(df[col])[0])
    artists.append(lines.copy())

anim = ArtistAnimation(fig, artists, interval=500, repeat_delay=1000)
```

[image]

The drawback here is that each artist is either drawn or not, i.e. you can't draw only part of a `Line2D` object without doing clipping. If this is not compatible with your use case then you can try using `FuncAnimation` with `blit=True` and chunking the data to be plotted each time as well as using `set_data()` instead of clearing and redrawing on every iteration. An example of this using the same data from above:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

n = 500
nf = 100
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, n)
df = pd.DataFrame({'cos(x)' : np.cos(x), 
                   'sin(x)' : np.sin(x),
                   'tan(x)' : np.tan(x),
                   'sin(cos(x))' : np.sin(np.cos(x))})

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(5,5), dpi=50)
lines = []
for ax, col in zip(axs.flatten(), df.columns):
    lines.append(ax.plot([], lw=0.5)[0])
    ax.set_xlim(x[0] - x[-1]*0.05, x[-1]*1.05)
    ax.set_ylim([min(df[col].values)*1.05, max(df[col].values)*1.05])
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, bottom=False, left=False, labelleft=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0, left=0.02, right=0.98, bottom=0.02, top=0.98)
plt.margins(1, 1)
c = int(n / nf)
def animate(i):
    if (i != nf - 1):
        for line, col in zip(lines, df.columns):
            line.set_data(x[:(i+1)*c], df[col].values[:(i+1)*c])
    else:
        for line, col in zip(lines, df.columns):
            line.set_data(x, df[col].values)        
    return lines

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=2000/nf, frames=nf, blit=True)
```

[image]

---

#### Edit

In response to the comments, here is the implementation of a chunking scheme using the updated code in the question:

```py
x = benchmark_returns.index
y = benchmark_returns['Crypto 30'] 
y2 = benchmark_returns['Dow Jones 30']
y3 = benchmark_returns['NASDAQ'] 
y4 = benchmark_returns['S&P 500']

line, = ax.plot(x, y, color='k')
line2, = ax.plot(x, y2, color = 'b')
line3, = ax.plot(x, y3, color = 'r')
line4, = ax.plot(x, y4, color = 'g')

n = len(x)  # Total number of rows
c = 50      # Chunk size
def update(num):
    end = num * c if num * c < n else n - 1
    line.set_data(x[:end], y[:end])
    line2.set_data(x[:end], y2[:end])
    line3.set_data(x[:end], y3[:end])
    line4.set_data(x[:end], y4[:end])

    return line, line2, line3, line4,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval = c, blit = True)
plt.show()
```

or, more succinctly

```py
cols = benchmark_returns.columns.values
# or, for only a subset of the columns
# cols = ['Crypto 30', 'Dow Jones 30', 'NASDAQ', 'S&P 500']
colors = ['k', 'b', 'r', 'g']
lines = []
for c, col in zip(cols, colors):
    lines.append(ax.plot(benchmark_returns.index, benchmark_returns[col].values, c=c)[0])

n = len(benchmark_returns.index)
c = 50  # Chunk size
def update(num):
    end = num * c if num * c < n else n - 1
    for line, col in zip(lines, cols):
        line.set_data(benchmark_returns.index, benchmark_returns[col].values[:end])

    return lines

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval = c, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

and if you need it to stop updating after a certain time simply set the `frames` argument and `repeat=False` in `FuncAnimation()`.

Comment: I have tried this however the runtime isn't the best. It appears that as the data scales the fps drops catastrophically.

Comment: @HamishGibson That is to some extent inevitable, of course there are ways to mitigate it (using `blit`, using `set_data()` instead of clearing and replotting, etc) but still at a certain scale it becomes an issue of hardware regardless. The only real way to guarantee an FPS which is unaffected by data size is to save the animation instead of displaying it live.

Comment: I have managed to get a solution working with `set_data()`. How would I use clear in this case however?

Comment: @HamishGibson I'm not sure I understand your question - when I said 'clearing and replotting' I was referring to the use of `ax.clear` and `plt.plot` instead of `set_data`..... is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Apologies, let me reitoriate. I have a working solution that uses `FuncAnimation()`. In the relevant update function, I use `set_data()`, but I'm not using any `clear()` method at all. How would such a `clear()` method work?

Comment: @HamishGibson Using the method I've outlined in this answer or a different method?

Comment: Using a different method, sorry I should have clarified.

Comment: @HamishGibson All good, you should consider posting the solution you found as an answer. That way future users who come across the question can make use of it as well

Comment: Yes I absolutely will. But my current working version doesn't wield any way of clearing the screen. Could this be why it slows down? Could it be the case that it plots a new line each time instead of just updating the current one?

Comment: @HamishGibson That would certainly lead to some added inefficiency. In that case I would update the question with your current code - I will be better able to tell you how to go about clearing things if I see the code your using now

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your assistance. I have updated my code in the original question accordingly.

Comment: @HamishGibson How large is the data frame?

Comment: Each line has 5,760 data points. Which I know sounds like a lot but surely matplotlib is scalable enough for this?

Comment: @HamishGibson Matplotlib is more than capable of handling it, however the way your current code works it is generating 5,760 frames - that will create a **massive** memory footprint. I wouldn't be surprised if you're exceeding your RAM and getting slowed down by swapping.... even if you're not hitting swap territory that's still going to slow the animation down. The solution for that is to load the data in chunks (as in my answer) - i.e. plot 10 rows at a time. I can update my code to demonstrate that in your example if you're interested

Comment: Yes please that would be extremely helpful. I see where you're coming from now in regards to memory usage. I just tested how it would run by plotting it daily not hourly (a 24x reduction) and it ran much faster. But I would still prefer to use hourly data as originally planned.

Comment: @HamishGibson Take a look at my edit, let me know if it helps

Comment: Yes the your first solution worked perfectly, thank you. I tried the second one but I ran into some errors. I might stick to the first one. I have 3 more similar graphs I want to try and plot. But good that I now have a 'proof of concept' working version I can now go off. Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it immensely. Thank you.

Comment: @HamishGibson Glad to help, don't forget to mark the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so the question is marked as such for future users.

Answer (score 1):

You can just update the data into the line element like so:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
liner, = ax.plot()
plt.ion()
plt.show()
for i in range(len(benchmark_returns.values)):
    liner.set_ydata(benchmark_returns['Crypto 30'][:i])
    liner.set_xdata(benchmark_returns.index[:i])
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

Comment: I got a ``` File "results.py", line 91, in <module>
    liner, = ax.plot()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)``` error instead

Comment: I managed to fix the error but the runtime is horrendous, any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: If you can use NumPy arrays as inputs rather than pandas series, you could see potential improvement in the runtime.

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003837/fast-plotting-data-in-python) SO helpful. There are other ways that offer faster times than `matplotlib`.