# How to do dynamic matplotlib plotting with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation

I have a dataframe called `benchmark_returns` and `strategy_returns`. I want to find a way to plot the datapoints in a nice animation style. I am aware that there is a `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()`, however this typically is only used for a real-time updating of csv files etc but in my case I know all the data I want to use.

I have also tried using the crude `plt.pause(0.01)` method, however this drastically slows down as the number of points get plotted.

In my case, I have all the data I want to plot and I don't need to rely on any external source such as an online API.

Here is my code so far

```
#Current display of static 2x2 subplot of all dataframes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1).plot(benchmark_returns)
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2).plot(strategy_returns['BTC-USD'])
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3).plot(strategy_returns['ETH-USD'])
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4).plot(strategy_returns['LTC-USD'])
fig = plt.figure()

#Attempt at doing an animation with plt.pause
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i in range(len(benchmark_returns.values)):
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(benchmark_returns.index[:i], benchmark_returns['Crypto 30'][:i])
    plt.pause(0.01)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't see why you can't use `FuncAnimation`. Your case seems to be exactly the usecase FuncAnimation was designed for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do dynamic matplotlib plotting with a fixed pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607750/how-to-do-dynamic-matplotlib-plotting-with-a-fixed-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Maybe I haven't seen an example of how FuncAnimation was applied to a similar situation to mine. As all that I have seen so far is cases which involve reading from a real time live CSV file.